# Questions about $C^*$-algebra approach to QM

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian

I'm trying to read *An Introduction to the Mathematical Structure of Quantum Mechanics* by Strocchi, which (as I understand) takes measurements first and states second, and argues that if we allow observables to be formally added then they form a Jordan algebra, which usually can be embedded into a $C^*$-algebra. Then he argues that a physical dynamical system should mean a $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and a one-parameter group of automorphisms, which leads to the Schrödinger equation $i\frac{d}{dt}\Psi(t)=H\ \Psi(t)$, where $H$ is a self-adjoint operator derived from those automorphisms. Here are my questions:

1. Is there any physical meaning to the sum $A+B$ of two observables, say position+momentum (although these are unbounded so strictly speaking should be some bounded functions of them)? Or in Strocchi's terms, is there an "operational definition"? We certainly cannot carry out both $A$ and $B$ and then add the results.
2. How do I know which self-adjoint operator $H$ to use in concrete situation, such as a particle with one degree of freedom moving in a potential? It seems Strocchi just writes down the Hamiltonian $H=-\frac{\Delta}{2m}+V(x)$ without much justification. Is the particular form of $H$ still somehow taken as an axiom, or can it be "derived" in a more $C^*$-algebraic way?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to 1 is:

*Generally speaking there is no operational meaning for $aA+bB$ in terms of $A$ and $B$, when $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ (with correct physical dimensions) and $A,B$ are selfadjoint operators (also unbounded) and they represent incompatible observables. If one knows the instruments for measuring $A$ and $B$, there is no way or suggestion in Quantum Theory to find an instrument for measuring $aA+bB$.*

This is one of the open problems with the formalism of Quantum Theory using $C^*$ algebras, von Neumann algebras or any other more elementary approach.

What we know is only that **if** $aA+bB$ has physical meaning and there is an instrument capable to measure it, then the expectation values must satisfy
$$\langle aA+bB\rangle_\rho = a\langle A\rangle_\rho + b\langle B\rangle_\rho$$
for every state $\rho$.

If $A$ and $B$ are elements of a representation of a Lie algebra and the unitary operators generated by them are physical symmetries then there is some chance to know how to measure a linear combination of $A$ and $B$ when we know how to measure $A$ and $B$. But it is a very special case.
(However see [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11005-020-01332-7) paper of mine and collaborators for the general case.)

The answer to 2 is quite vague. In general there is no way to pass form classical observables to  "quantum versions" of them in terms of selfadjoint operators. The mathematical instrument devoted to do it is called **quantization map**. There is a number of issues with these mathematical tools and many no-go theorems proving that the properties of those maps   are not the ones one (naively) expects.  There are some good proposals for quantization maps but none is trivial.

However sometimes everything goes right and magic takes place. That is the case of the spectra of atoms and many other cases.

Comment: We do know empirically that energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges are locally conserved quantities. They are "natural" in the sense that their conservation stems from symmetries of spacetime. Among these only angular momentum and charges are truly "quantized". Energy and momentum are forming a continuum (unless we assume some unusual geometry for spacetime like compactified dimensions). Isn't the discussion about other "observables" more of a mathematical artifact that comes from how we define the theory?

Comment: Maybe you are right. At least some of the mathematically possible observables are a mathematical artifact. In that sense it is dangerous to assume from scratch that the (bounded) observables form an algebra...

Comment: In any case, I haven't heard about quantization maps, yet. I will read up on them. Thanks for mentioning them.

Comment: Do you mean $a$ and $b$ need to have unit for $aA+bB$ to make sense? But there are infinitely many choices. Which one should we choose? It becomes even more problematic when we want to make sense of $A+B+C$

Answer (score 2):

In the $C^\ast$-algebraic approach, much like in every other approach, the *meaning* of specific observables needs to ultimately come from physics. Sometimes the sum of observables is something very meaningful (e.g. the sum of angular momenta of different subsystems), sometimes it is not (e.g. the sum of position and momentum). There is no general meaning.

A general guideline is to consider dimensional analysis: As physical quantities, position and momentum have different dimensions, so adding them makes no sense. Unless your specific problem has some natural constants that can be combined to yield a conversion constant $k$ with dimensions of $\frac{\text{length}}{\text{momentum}}$ so that $x+kp$ has the correct dimensions, you should not expect any non-trivial linear combination of the position and momentum operator to have physical meaning.

Likewise, there is no magic nor technology that can derive the correct Hamiltonian for a given system out of thin air - this is not unique to quantum physics, you cannot derive the form of the Hamiltonian in classical Hamiltonian mechanics either, you need to know that it is what physicists "intuitively" mean by the energy of a system and then know how to get expression for that energy that fit into the Hamiltonian framework. Ultimately the correct Hamiltonian is the one that yields equations of motion whose solutions correctly predict the behaviour of the system as observed, both in classical and quantum physics.

The form $p^2 + V(x)$ for a Hamiltonian is ubiquitous in - again, both classical and quantum - physics, and the justification for using the same Hamiltonians in quantum mechanics as in classical mechanics are the various formulations of [quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization), where we want to turn the classical Poisson algebra of functions on the Hamiltonian phase space into the quantum $C^\ast$-algebra of observables.

Comment: Maybe position+momentum doesn't have physical *significance*, but is it something that can actually be measured in lab? Like given two procedures that measure position and momentum respectively, how to build from them a procedure that measures the sum? I didn't think unit is a huge problem since ultimately an experimental apparatus merely returns some number, not number+unit.

Comment: @Lxm No, you cannot get an apparatus that measures the sum of two non-commuting observables just because you have apparatuses that measure the individual observables.

Comment: The only locally conserved observables are energy, momentum, angular momentum and charges (like electric charge and quantum numbers like lepton number). Position is not a conserved physical quantity to begin with. The only "position:" we are measuring in quantum mechanics is the position of the detector. It is NOT the position of the quantum. The "structure of quantum mechanics" that you are looking at here is the mathematical structure of the theory and not the structure of nature.

Comment: @Lxm no, experimental devices DO return number + unit. The number I get for a length measurement depends on if I use an imperial or SI ruler as my measurement device. I’ll get different number in each case but the measurement is the same. This is because the units contravary with the measured “number”.

Comment: @Jagerber48 In that case $A+B$ would be even less justified, though. But I'm still not super convinced. I feel like unit is part of the experimental design but not part of the measurement. If a random guy knowing nothing about the experiment walks into the lab they can still read the number, but they may not know the unit used.

Comment: @Lxm Sure... it is possible to my height divided the length of a meter to the height of Mt. Everest divided by the length of a kilometer. Or we can add my height divided by the length of a kilometer to the mass of the sun divided by the mass of a nanogram... That is true...